# Hidden Input and AngularJS ng-model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS to calculate total price for product when I add Quantity. I have a code as below:

```
<div ng-app="TheApp">
<div ng-controller="TheController">
    <input type="hidden" name="Price" value="100" ng-model="Price" />
    <input type="text" name="Quantity" ng-model="Quantity" />
    Total Price:{{TotalPrice}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="click()">Add Items</button>
</div>
```

Inside my controller I have:

```
    $scope.TotalPrice = $scope.Price * $scope.Quantity;
```

I know Angular does not support hidden but I am looking for the best practice to solve the issue.
Please consider button is not for calculating TotalPrice but sending final result. I want it to be updated real time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your case since you just want to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="Price" ng-init="Price=100;" ng-value="Price"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ghd9c8q3/)

Comment: Voila ! Thanks a lot :)))

Comment: There's no need for a hidden field. The init logic can be placed in the controller `<div ng-controller="TheController" ng-init="Price=100;">`

Answer (score 11):

> Angular just ignores hidden input elements.(ng-model doesn't support
>   input field)

If you want that value in `ng-model` it self, then it shouldn't be of type hidden. You could solve this problem by hiding that div by doing `display:none` instead of giving type hidden or using `ng-show` directive make it hidden.

```
<div ng-controller="TheController">
    <input type="text" ng-show="false" name="Price" value="100" ng-model="Price" />
    <input type="text" name="Quantity" ng-model="Quantity" />
    Total Price:{{TotalPrice}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="click()">Add Items</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good idea too, rendering a normal input field with `ng-model` but using a `display:none`. Clever work around suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need to use a hidden value in the HTML, since it's not altered by user, you can simply initialize this value in controller's scope and update your "TotalPrice" value when the user adds any quantity or you can also use ng-init in html to initialize it, but it is not a good practice to use ng-init as stated by the docs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: I was attempting to use a hidden input as well until I realized, you are correct, the data I needed was available by passing an entire object to the controller, like, Front End: `ng-submit="newComment(post)"` and Back-End: `$scope.newComment = function(post) { console.log(post._id) }`. This will pass the entire post object into the controller, and from there properties (like `_id`) can be accessed. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it without clicks

```
<input type="hidden" name="Price" value="100" ng-model="Price" ng-change="updateTotalPrice()" />
<input type="text" name="Quantity" ng-model="Quantity" ng-change="updateTotalPrice()" />
```

or if you want to do it on click

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addItem()">Add Items</button>
```

and then in addItem

```
function addItem(){
   //increment quantity 
   //call to updateTotalPrice()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Price` value inside the click function as an argument like:

```
<div ng-app="TheApp">
<div ng-controller="TheController">

  <input type="text" name="Quantity" ng-model="Quantity" />
  Total Price:{{TotalPrice}}
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="click(100)">Add Items</button>
</div>
```

Or if you have your `Product` info loaded into $scope variable you just call it directly from controller and do not nedd to pass `Price` as hidden or in click function

```
$scope.Product  =  productFactory.get();

$scope.click = function() {
 $scope.TotalPrice = $scope.Product.Price * $scope.Quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.price = 10;
```

Use double brackets to capture the scope value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Price" value="{{price}}"/>
```